# Hive partitioned column doesn't appear in rdd via sc.textFile

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

The Hive partitioned column is not the part of the underlying saved data, I need to know how it can be pulled via `sc.textFile(filePath)` syntax to be loaded in RDD.

I know the other way of creating hive context and all but was wondering is there a way I can directly get it via `sc.textFile(filePath)` syntax and use it.

Answer (score 0):

By partitioning the data by a column when saving, that columns data will be stored in the file structure and not in the actual files. Since, `sc.textFile(filePath)` is made for reading single files I do not believe it supports reading partitioned data.

I would **recommend** reading the data as a dataframe, for example:

```
val df = hiveContext.read().format("orc").load("path/to/table/")
```

---

The `wholeTextFiles()` method could also be used. Then you would get a tuple of `(file path, file data)` and from that it should be possible to parse out the partitioned data column and then add it as a new column.

If the storage size is no problem, then an alternative solution would be to store the information of the partitioned column twice. Once in the file structure (done by partitioning on that column), and once more in the data itself. This is achieved by **duplicating the column** before saving it to file. Say the column in question is named `colA`,

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("colADup", $"colA")
df2.write.partitionBy("colADup").orc("path/to/save/")
```

This can also easily be extended to multiple columns.

Comment: Was wondering is there a way like extracting the partitioned column name and then appending it to the element created via sc.textFile(filePath). One way i could think of is to partition as well as have the column in the file too -- one would be used to name the folder the other one will be part of the data file but dont know its the right way or not. Having this via HiveContext is fine but trying to find a way via core spark.

Comment: @Jay Yes, it is possible to do it like that as well. Added that method to the answer as well as one using the `wholeTextFiles()` method.